# No log output after upgrading to NLog v5.0.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

In our ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, and command-line programs we have been using NLog for many years.

In an ASP.NET Core app targeting `net6.0`, the following configuration works when using `NLog version 4.7.15` and `NLog.Extensions.Hosting version 1.7.5`. When upgrading both packages to version 5.0.x (e.g. the latest available version, `5.0.4`), logging stops working. **Nothing is logged: The log file remains empty.**

The application is supposed to use the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging filters as defined in `appsettings.json` - see below.

I've read [NLog 5.0 - List of major changes](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html)
 many times and tried to workaround the breaking changes. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work.

Our setup is below, hopefully someone is able to help. Thank you!

---

#### ASP.NET Core app targeting `net6.0`, using `NLog version 4.7.15` and `NLog.Extensions.Hosting version 1.7.5`

As soon as I upgrade to `NLog version 5.0.4` and `NLog.Extensions.Hosting version 5.0.4`, the logging breaks. Nothing is logged any more.

##### NLog.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd http://nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off"
      internalLogFile="D:\Logs\StevenVolckaert.WebService\nlog-internal.log">

  <!-- Docs @ https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file -->
  <!-- ASP.NET Core examples @ https://github.com/akovac35/Logging.Samples -->

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.Hosting" />
  </extensions>

  <!-- ConfigSetting Layout Renderer @ https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer -->

  <variable name="ApplicationName" value="${configsetting:item=ApplicationName:default=application}" />
  <variable name="BuildNumber" value="${configsetting:item=BuildNumber:default=undefined}" />
  <variable name="EnvironmentName" value="${configsetting:item=EnvironmentName:default=undefined}" />
  <variable name="LogDirectory" value="${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${basedir}logs:inner=${configsetting:item=NLog.LogDirectory}}" />

  <!-- https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#targets -->

  <targets>
    <target
       xsi:type="Console"
       name="Console"
       layout="${longdate} ${threadid:padding=2} ${uppercase:${level:padding=5}} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=toString}">
    </target>
    <target
      xsi:type="File"
      name="LogFile"
      fileName="${var:LogDirectory}\${var:ApplicationName}.log"
      layout="${longdate} ${threadid:padding=2} ${uppercase:${level:padding=5}} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=toString}"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveFileName="${var:LogDirectory}\Archive\{#}.${var:ApplicationName}.log"
      archiveNumbering="Date"
      archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
      maxArchiveDays="90">
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules -->

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="Console,LogFile" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

##### appsettings.json

```json
{
  "ApplicationName": "StevenVolckaert.WebService",
  "BuildNumber": null,
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultDatabaseConnection": ""
  },
  "EnvironmentName": "Local",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "NLog": {
    "LogDirectory": "D:\\Logs\\StevenVolckaert.WebService\\"
  }
}
```

##### Program.cs

```cs
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services
            .AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder
                    .ClearProviders()
                    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
                    .AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
                    .AddNLog(builder.Configuration, new NLogProviderOptions { RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false });
            });

        // code removed for brevity

        var app = builder.Build();

        // code removed for brevity

        app.Run();
    }
```

I've tried adding the `filters` element to the `logger` rule, specifying `defaultAction="Log"`, but this doesn't make a difference: Still no output in the logging.

```xml
   <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="Console,LogFile">
      <filters defaultAction="Log" />
    </logger>
  </rules>
```

Comment: While I do not have an answer, I took a brief look at the v5.0 docs, and it appears there are a few breaking changes, as well as some NLog Targeting changes which your sample layouts have yet to be updated. Additionally, I would recommend reviewing the section on _NLog InternalLogger will not initialize itself from app.config or environment variables_ to aid in your troubleshooting.

Comment: Is it possible that you might have to also install `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` package?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I've just added `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` and I've added it to the NLog.config (`<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>` to the `extensions` element). Unfortunately, this doesn't make a difference. Still no logging in the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the issue is caused by this [new default-value](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/501):

> NLogProviderOptions.LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog"

The change in default-value causes the `"NLog"`-section to become reserved, and intended for having [NLog.config in appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json). This works together with [SchemaStore](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore) that provides basic-intellisense when editing the now reserved `"NLog"`-section.

This probably causes NLog.Extensions.Logging to lookup the `"NLog"`-section in the appsettings.json where it finds this:

```json
{
  "NLog": {
    "LogDirectory": "D:\\Logs\\StevenVolckaert.WebService\\"
  }
}
```

After having "loaded" this empty NLog-configuration, then it skips further attempts and doesn't load your `NLog.config`-file.

I suggest that you remove the `"NLog"`-section and change it into this (And updates `NLog.config` to `${configsetting:NLogDirectory}`):

```json
{
   "NLogDirectory": "D:\\Logs\\StevenVolckaert.WebService\\"
}
```

Sorry about the bad experience, but it was done to make [NLog.config in appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json) work out of the box (Making it closer to a first class citizen).

P.S Consider [updating your program.cs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6#3-update-programcs) like this (But I encourage that you remove `RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false` and instead make use of [NLog finalMinLevel](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter)):

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseNLog(new NLogProviderOptions { RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false });
var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: @StevenVolckaert Updated NLog v5 release notes to include this breaking-change: https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-makes-nlog-section-reserved-in-appsettingsjson - Thank you for highlighting this.

Comment: Thank you @Rolf Kristensen! I changed the `NLog` key in appsettings.json to `NLogSettings` and I confirm the logging works now! I've read the docs explaining `finalMinLevel` a few times but I'm having trouble understanding how it works. How should I adapt NLog.config to use `finalMinLevel` and still use the filters as defined in appsettings.json in the `Logging` section? Thanks!

Comment: @StevenVolckaert I only recommend using `finalMinLevel` to avoid having filtering configuration multiple places. If you have decided never to use the NLog filtering logic for controlling target-output, then I guess you can keep `RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false`. Notice that you can also do this: `<logger name="*" minlevel="${configsetting:Logging.LogLevel.Default:whenEmpty=Trace}" writeTo="Console,LogFile">`

Comment: Thanks again @Rolf Kristensen for the suggestions!